# What can edit an .ai files TEXT layer (besides Illustrator)?

Tags: java, text, adobe

so, i have **CS6** on Mac (OS **Mavericks**).

my Mac took a nose dive recently. long story super short... i have a new mac & re-installed my CS6 on it.

but, in order to launch Illustrator, it requires that i install **JAVA** too. and i just really don't wanna do that. picky & trivial of me? maybe; but it's a desire i have. *and that's a different topic i don't really wish to get in to in THIS thread*.

additionally, i've just grown more & more irritated & unhappy with Adobe's apps *(also a discussion for a different thread).*

so i just thought i'd see if there were any new vector graphics apps out there that could fulfill my needs. **the most important of which would be to** open my pre-existing .ai files *(check: there are several good ones - like Sketch, iDraw, Bluetail, Intaglio, Inkscape, etc)* AND be able to **directly edit pre-existing text in its layers** -BUT- none of them seem to be able to edit text layers *(and yes, i have the same fonts)*. they all appear to open the ai file as a raster image or vector image, but no layers nor editable text.

**so i'm just wondering if i've missed something or if it's true - that the proprietary ai format is unusable fully in any other app - or is there one i've missed or a method i failed to find. (?)**

thanks much.

Comment: maybe you can use Gimp I know it isn't a Vector Graphic Progam but it has built in support for many Filetypes and if it hasn't there still may be the chance that there is a plugin/addon which will add the support to it. Also there may be the chance to change the suffix to pdf and open them in a PDF Editor according to this blog entry http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/opening-adobe-illustrator-ai-files-when-you-don-t-have-adobe-illustrator i found by just googleing "open adobe ilustrator files" - forinformation i havn't tried out so no prove that it works.

Comment: @Konqui - thanks for the suggestions! but i haven't been able to find any Gimp plugins that'd help with this sitch. and nothing i've read about Inkscape really answers the specifics of my question. so i guess i'm just gonna have to try it. CURIOUS: i got a couple emails that there were more than your 1 reply here, yet, you're it. odd.

Comment: Don't know maybe i generated more than one mail cause i edited my comment to add the link. Found some other interesting blog entry about Gimp and *.ai Files http://dorothyswords.blogspot.ch/2012/02/lets-try-gimp-lesson-3-opening-ai-files.html?m=1

Comment: thanks again KONQUI! i'll just go ahead & install gimp & play with it as well as inkwell - but i've read that even tho this new link you sent is doable, it rasterizes the layers from illustrator; so they're not vector anymore. but i'll play around with it & post back next chance i get in case anybody's interested. thanks again!